# Amazon lambda HTML meta tags

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I'd like to know if it's possible to add some meta tags to the html returned by cloudfront, with lambda functions.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Lamda@edge events do not contain the response body. You could however use a origin request event and make the call to the origin in the lambda and return the modified response body.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Should I find a way to have that html, parser it, edit it and then return it modified then?

Comment: Otherwise I don't see anything in the payload that could allow me to add meta tags directly in the html rendered...

Comment: The origin request event is a Lambda@edge event, no?

Comment: Yes. The lambda that handles the request could make the call to the origin, modify the response and return the modified response to the caller. CloudFront in this use case would not make the call to the origin.